# How to override "Save Before Run" for a particular task

Tags: vscode-tasks

I have the following as a part of tasks.json to check the syntax of Ada code. It references a bash script, check.sh.

```
    {
        "label": "Check Ada",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/check.sh",
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$ada"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "revealProblems": "onProblem",
            "focus": true,
            "panel": "dedicated",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": true
        }
    }
```

Not necessary to know, but check.sh merely calls an Ada tool, gnatmake, like this:

```
fileName=$1
echo "Checking $fileName"
gnatmake -q -c -gnatc -u -P"/Users/me/bla/bla/bla/build.gpr" "$fileName"
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
    echo "Checks OK."
else
    echo "Checks bad."
fi
```

In Settings, I have

```
Task: Save Before Run
Save all dirty editors before running a task. -> Always
```

I prefer this Setting when doing other tasks such as building or build-and-run. However, when merely doing a syntax check as above, I do not want to save first, in case I have a lot of new errors and want to revert to the previous state.

Is there a way of overriding the Save Before Run in Settings for *only* the a particular task, such as the Check Ada task here?

I barely know what I am doing so it would be helpful if you address me as a fairly smart fifth-grader.